# Optimum neuron and neural layer size for accuracy and efficiency

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I am working on Deep Neural Networks and was wondering about the following question:

What is the best number of layers and number of neurons per layer in general for ***optimum accuracy***?

As per this picture:
[image: Image1]

Would the optimum numbers be equal to the feature size, so that each feature's influence on each other set of features is taken into account?

Also, would the answer differ if we were looking for ***optimum accuracy and efficiency***?

Thank you, any insights are appreciated!

Edit:

These answers are informative. I still feel like they don't address specifically the first part of my question. To clarify: Is there a maximum amount of neurons and layers that when applied would be equally granular to the data, and thus adding more neurons or layers would be redundant? I assume infinite layers to a 3 feature data set would at some point become unnecessary. Thanks again for all reads and replies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no general answer to your question. Such quantities are called hyper-parameters and their choosing is an open problem, and a big part of the art of machine learning. [Here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-hyperparameters-in-machine-learning) is a discussion on the topic on Quora.

For a good introduction into neural networks and their inner-workings, see [improving the way neural networks learn](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html).

To gain intuition on choosing such hyper-parameters, and constructing networks architecture, one would be wise to study known successful models:

[LeNet](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf) : The first successful applications of Convolutional Networks were developed by Yann LeCun in 1990’s. Of these, the best known is the LeNet architecture that was used to read zip codes, digits, etc.

[AlexNet](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks) : The first work that popularized Convolutional Networks in Computer Vision

[GoogleNet](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842) : The ILSVRC 2014 winner

Study how they are designed for the particulars of the problem being solved.

Comment: Thanks, Ziga. Also, I found this information helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088687/layers-and-neurons-of-a-neural-network?rq=1

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. If you would like to see a simple working implementation of backpropagation and training, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687180/neural-network-backpropagation-not-working/40550231#40550231)

Comment: That is a little more in depth than I am looking to go at the moment, but very informative. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345079/estimating-the-number-of-neurons-and-number-of-layers-of-an-artificial-neural-ne?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

From [Is there any method for choosing the number of layers and neurons?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/232393/12359):

There is no direct way to find the optimal number of them: people empirically try and see (e.g., using cross-validation). The most common search techniques are random, manual, and grid searches.

There exist more advanced techniques such as

1) Gaussian processes. Example:

- Franck Dernoncourt, Ji Young Lee [Optimizing Neural Network Hyperparameters with Gaussian Processes for Dialog Act Classification](http://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08703), IEEE SLT 2016.

2) [Neuro-evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution). Examples:

- Zaremba, Wojciech. Ilya Sutskever. Rafal Jozefowicz "[An empirical exploration of recurrent network architectures.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9021528542952156548&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" (2015): used evolutionary computation to find optimal RNN structures.
- Franck Dernoncourt. "[The medial Reticular Formation: a neural substrate for action selection? An evaluation via evolutionary computation.](http://www.francky.me/doc/mrf2011-HEC-ISIR-ENS_en.pdf)". Master's Thesis. École Normale
  Supérieure Ulm. 2011. Used evolutionary computation to find connections in the ANN.
- Bayer, Justin, Daan Wierstra, Julian Togelius, and Jürgen Schmidhuber. "[Evolving memory cell structures for sequence learning.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14945304742464379854&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" In International Conference on Artificial Neural Networks, pp. 755-764. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2009.: used evolutionary computation to find optimal RNN structures.

Also relevant:  [To design a Multilayer Perceptron, should I use more units per layer and less layers or more layers and less units, which is better?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/244975/12359)

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to your question.But by changing these parameters would able to reach an optimal solution.

- Format of input data,
- Number and size of layers,
- Amount of spatial pooling,
- Filter dimension,
- Learning hyperparameters(learning rate, momentum, batch size, dropout
  probability, an amount of  regularization applied)